# C# ForEach Loop With ASync Tasks & Dependent Post ASync Tasks

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, parallel-foreach

I'm having trouble trying to correctly architect the most efficient way to iterate several async tasks launched from a request object and then performing some other async tasks that depend on both the request object and the result of the first async task. I'm running a C# lambda function in AWS. I've tried a model like this (error handling and such has been omitted for brevity):

```
public async Task MyAsyncWrapper()
{
  List<Task> Tasks = new List<Task>();
  foreach (var Request in Requests) 
  {
    var Continuation = this.ExecuteAsync(Request).ContinueWith(async x => {
      var KeyValuePair<bool, string> Result = x.Result;
      if (Result.Key == true)
      {
        await this.DoSomethingElseAsync(Request.Id, Request.Name, Result.Value);
        Console.WriteLine("COMPLETED");
      }
    }

    Tasks.Add(Continuation);
  }

  Task.WaitAll(Tasks.ToArray());
}
```

This approach results in the `DoSomethingElseAsync()` method not really getting awaited on and in a lot of my Lambda Function calls, I never get the "COMPLETED" output. I've also approached this in this method:

```
public async Task MyAsyncWrapper()
{
  foreach (var Request in Requests) 
  {
    KeyValuePair<bool, string> Result = await this.ExecuteAsync(Request);

    if (Result.Key == true)
    {
      await this.DoSomethingElseAsync(Request.Id, Request.Name, Result.Value);
      Console.WriteLine("COMPLETED");
    }
  }
}
```

This works, but I think it's wasteful, since I can only execute one iteration of the loop while waiting on the asnyc's to finish. I also have referenced [Interleaved Tasks](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/08/02/processing-tasks-as-they-complete/) but the issue is that I basically have two loops, one to populate the tasks, and another to iterate them after they've completed, where I don't have access to the original `Request` object anymore. So basically this:

```
List<Task<KeyValuePair<bool, string>>> Tasks = new List<Task<KeyValuePair<bool, string>>>();

foreach (var Request in Requests)
{
  Tasks.Add(ths.ExecuteAsync(Request);
}

foreach (Task<KeyValuePair<bool, string>> ResultTask in Tasks.Interleaved())
{
  KeyValuePair<bool, string> Result = ResultTask.Result;
  //Can't access the original request for this method's parameters
  await this.DoSomethingElseAsync(???, ???, Result.Value);
}
```

Any ideas on better ways to implement this type of async chaining in a foreach loop? My ideal approach wouldn't be to return the request object back as part of the response from `ExecuteAsync()`, so I'd like to try and find other options if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I may be misinterpreting, but why not move your "iteration" into it's own function and then use `Task.WhenAll` to wait for all iterations in parallel.

```
public async Task MyAsyncWrapper()
{
  var allTasks = Requests.Select(ProcessRequest);

  await Task.WhenAll(allTasks);
}

private async Task ProcessRequest(Request request)
{
    KeyValuePair<bool, string> Result = await this.ExecuteAsync(request);

    if (Result.Key == true)
    {
      await this.DoSomethingElseAsync(request.Id, request.Name, Result.Value);
      Console.WriteLine("COMPLETED");
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this may be really helpful. I'm gonna try it out and see if it works.

Comment: This solution worked for me and significantly reduced the amount of code I had written to perform these loops on multiple different request types.

Answer (score 3):

Consider using TPL dataflow:

```
var a = new TransformBlock<Input, OutputA>(async Input i=>
{
    // do something async.
    return new OutputA();
});

var b = new TransformBlock<OutputA, OutputB>(async OutputA i =>
{
    // do more async.
    return new OutputB();
});

var c = new ActionBlock<OutputB>(async OutputB i =>
{
    // do some final async.
});

a.LinkTo(b, new DataflowLinkOptions { PropogateCompletion = true });
b.LinkTo(c, new DataflowLinkOptions { PropogateCompletion = true });

// push all of the items into the dataflow.
a.Post(new Input());
a.Complete();

// wait for it all to complete.
await c.Completion;
```

Comment: So I see how this how this can work for a single chain of actions, but will this work as expected in a foreach loop where `Input` is a `Request` so that I can ensure that each `c` is complete before exiting the method?

Comment: This would replace a `foreach` loop: instead of having your code inside the loop, your loop would merely `Post` data into the dataflow.